# Why does VS Code suggest me auto-imports via relative path instead of the path alias I defined in my tsconfig.json?

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, intellisense, tsconfig

My project structure is like this:

```
---- apps
---- libs
-------- index.ts
-------- commmon
-------- service
------------ index.ts
------------ src
---------------- index.ts
---------------- goods
-------------------- index.ts
-------------------- src
------------------------ index.ts
------------------------ goods.service.ts
```

[image]

Each `index.ts` have an export * from '...' statement.

And my `tsconfig.json` is down below:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "declaration": true,
    "removeComments": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "target": "es2017",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "incremental": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "strictNullChecks": false,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "strictBindCallApply": false,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": false,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": false,
    "paths": {
      "@frosticx/library": [
        "libs"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

I expect all import from libs should be `import { ... } from '@frosticx/library';`, However Vistual Studio does not regonize this path alias:
[image]

Manually specify `@frosticx/library` would work, but as you can see Visual Studio does not treat it as a module:
[image]

Comment: Related?: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/25876 also https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/32605, https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/51058, https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/31173, https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/59815

Answer (score 9):

Try setting `"typescript.preferences.importModuleSpecifier": "non-relative"` in your [settings.json file](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings#_settingsjson). The default value of that setting is `"shortest"`, which might be the problem here, since your alias seems to be longer than the relative path the module can be imported by.

Note: google-search suggestion: `github typescript issues auto import use tsconfig paths`.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. However it does not work unfortunately, Visual Studio does not seems to recognize to ``@frosticx/library``. The only suggestion is ``libs/service``

Answer (score 0):

I changed `paths` to this and it seems to work:

```
"paths": {
      "@frosticx/library": [
        "libs",
        "libs/*"
      ]
    }
```

I have no idea why it works, but seems to be an ugly solution.

Update:

This even makes `../xxx` to be `@frosticx/library` which is not expected.