# What is the correct way to export everything from my Typescript npm library

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, npm

I have a structure like this:

```
/
/lib
/lib/src/submodule/thing.ts
/lib/src/index.ts
/lib/package.json
/project
/project/src/index.ts
/project/package.json
```

/lib/package.json:

```
...
"main": "/build/index.js",
"types": "/build/index.d.ts",
...
```

/lib/src/submodule/thing.ts:

```
export const thing = "thing";
```

/lib/src/index.ts:

```
export * from "./submodule/thing";
```

/project/package.json:

```
...
"dependencies": {
  "lib": "../lib/"
...
```

/project/src/index.ts:

```
import { thing } from "lib";
```

As far I can tell, this compiles and works.

My issue is that VSCode is offering a relative import as on option for its autocomplete.

I get the following two when importing `thing`:

```
Add import from "lib"
Add import from "lib/build/submodule/thing.ts"
```

I only want the first option to be available, but I can't figure out what changes I need to make it order to achieve this - any ideas?

Note: I hope it's obvious that there are more submodules/classes that are exported from `lib`, I've tried to simplify the example. `lib` needs to remain a module that is referenced in `project`'s `package.json` (rather than just importing the source)

Comment: related? dup? https://stackoverflow.com/q/75820716/11107541

Comment: @starball - no I don't believe it is related, but thanks.